# Difficult reduction integral formula

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to prove that:

$$∫{dx\over \sin ^{m}x\cos ^{n}x}= {-1\over \left(m-1\right)\sin ^{m-1}x\cos ^{n-1}x} + {m+n-2\over m-1}∫ {dx\over \sin ^{m-2}x\cos ^{n}x}$$

but I don´t even know where to start I have tried integration by parts:

$$∫ {dx\over \sin ^{m}x\cos ^{n}x}=∫ \sin ^{-m}x\cos ^{-\left(n+1\right)}\cos xdx$$ then $$u= \cos ^{-\left(n+1\right)}x$$ $$du=-\left(n+1\right)\cos ^{-n-2}x\left(-\sin x\right)dx$$ $$dv=\sin ^{-m}x\cos x$$ $$v={\sin ^{-m+1}x\over \left(-m+1\right)}$$

hence:

$$∫{dx\over \sin ^{m}x\cos ^{n}x}= {-1\over \left(m-1\right)\sin ^{m-1}x\cos ^{n+1}x} + {\left(n+1\right)\over \left(m-1\right)}∫ {dx\over \sin ^{m-2}x\cos ^{n+2}x}$$

then I did: $$\sin ^{m-2}x\cos ^{n+2}x= \sin ^{m-2}x\cos ^{n}x\left(1-\sin ^{2}x\right)=\sin ^{m-2}x\cos ^{n}x-\sin ^{m}x\cos ^{n}x$$

but I dont know if this actually helps me, I would really appreciate your help whit this integral

Comment: http://planetmath.org/reductionformulas  and http://www.sosmath.com/CBB/viewtopic.php?p=140870

Answer (score 1):

I have a proof but it may seem a little bit ugly

in order to prove:

$$
\int{dx\over sin^{m}xcos^{n}x}= {-1\over (m-1)sin^{m-1}xcos^{n-1}x} + {m+n-2\over m-1}\int {dx\over sin^{m-2}xcos^{n}x}
$$

<=>

$$
(m-1)\int{dx\over sin^{m}xcos^{n}x} = {-1\over sin^{m-1}xcos^{n-1}x} + (m+n-2)\int {dx\over sin^{m-2}xcos^{n}x}
$$

<=>

$$
\int{(m-1)dx\over sin^{m}xcos^{n}x}-\int {(m+n-2)dx\over sin^{m-2}xcos^{n}x}={-1\over sin^{m-1}xcos^{n-1}x}
$$

<=>

$$
\int{\frac{m-1-(m+n-2)sin^2x}{sin^mxcos^nx}}dx={-1\over sin^{m-1}xcos^{n-1}x}
$$

<=>

$$
\int{\frac{(m-1)(1-sin^x)-(n-1)sin^2x}{sin^mxcos^nx}}dx = {-1\over sin^{m-1}xcos^{n-1}x}
$$

<=>

$$
\int{\frac{(m-1)cos^2x-(n-1)sin^2x}{sin^mxcos^nx}}dx = {-1\over sin^{m-1}xcos^{n-1}x}
$$

then we can specify the derivative of ${-1\over sin^{m-1}xcos^{n-1}x}$, and we can get what we want.

as each step can be reversed, then write it backwards and it is proved.